# trouble understanding this jquery function

Tags: jquery

```
var Pages = function() {
 this.VERSION = "1.0.0";
 this.pageScrollElement = 'html, body';
 this.$body = $('body');
 this.setUserOS();
 this.setUserAgent();
}

Pages.prototype.setUserOS = function() {
  var OSName = "";
  if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Win") != -1) OSName = "windows";
  if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Mac") != -1) OSName = "mac";
  if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("X11") != -1) OSName = "unix";
  if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Linux") != -1) OSName = "linux";
  this.$body.addClass(OSName);
}
Pages.prototype.setUserAgent = function() {
  if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Android|BlackBerry|iPhone|iPad|iPod|Opera Mini|IEMobile/i)) {
      this.$body.addClass('mobile');
  } else {
      this.$body.addClass('desktop');
      if (navigator.userAgent.match(/MSIE 9.0/)) {
          this.$body.addClass('ie9');
      }
  }
}

Pages.prototype.isVisibleXs = function() {
  (!$('#pg-visible-xs').length) && this.$body.append('<div id="pg-visible-xs" class="visible-xs" />');
  return $('#pg-visible-xs').is(':visible');
}

Pages.prototype.isVisibleSm = function() {
  (!$('#pg-visible-sm').length) && this.$body.append('<div id="pg-visible-sm" class="visible-sm" />');
  return $('#pg-visible-sm').is(':visible');
}

Pages.prototype.isVisibleMd = function() {
  (!$('#pg-visible-md').length) && this.$body.append('<div id="pg-visible-md" class="visible-md" />');
  return $('#pg-visible-md').is(':visible');
}

Pages.prototype.isVisibleLg = function() {
  (!$('#pg-visible-lg').length) && this.$body.append('<div id="pg-visible-lg" class="visible-lg" />');
  return $('#pg-visible-lg').is(':visible');
}

Pages.prototype.getUserAgent = function() {
  return $('body').hasClass('mobile') ? "mobile" : "desktop";
}
```

1. Why use prototype ?
   i may have gotten the concept of prototype wrong but we only have one object here.
2. Why this.$body = $('body') is used ?
   why not just go ahead and use $('body') ?
3. What exactly are the isVisibleXX functions doing ?

Comment: Every JavaScript object has a prototype. The prototype is also an object.All JavaScript objects inherit their properties and methods from their prototype.
- http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_prototypes.asp

Comment: `this.$body = $('body')` $('`body') defines one time to this.$('body'). it reduces to address to DOM element every time.

Comment: if there is not `ph-visible-xx` in the body, `<div id="pg-visible-xx" class="visible-lg" />` is added to body and `isVisibleXX` check(or return) that  `pg-visible-xx` is visible or hidden

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you are doing OOP, you want to put code that uses information form a class in that class. It is a design principle, and as such it is not strictly nececarry, but it might help you writing good and readable code.
2. Slight performance boost, since you do not have to find the body node every time you use it.
3. `isVisibleXs` is written in a quirky way that gives you short code, but is very hard to read. You could rewrite it to this:

   ```
   Pages.prototype.isVisibleXs = function() {
       if($('#pg-visible-xs').length > 0) {
           this.$body.append('<div id="pg-visible-xs" class="visible-xs" />');
       }
       return $('#pg-visible-xs').is(':visible');
   }
   ```

   Or, in plain english: Append a div with the ID `pg-visible-xs` to the body if there isn't already one. Return wheater it is visible or not.